# How can I migrate changes from views.py in an app in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-urls

I just started with Python/Django this week. I've been following the freeCodeCamp 4 hour course in youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5mRW0jo-U4&t=3885s). I didn't have any problem creating the virtual enviroment, the project and other apps that hold database models. However, at around the hour and 4 minutes mark of the video, the very same code the teacher is displaying in the video throws me an error.

He creates a new app called "pages" and in the views.py script codes this function

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def home_view():
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello World</h1>')
```

Then the pages app is included in the INSTALLED_APPS array, in the settings scripts

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pages',
]
```

The problems comes when I try to migrate the changes from pages. The 'python manage.py makemigrations' followed by the 'python manage.py migrate' commands don't detect any change in the views.py script of any of the apps, so when I try to import those views in the urls.py file, it throws an error. I don't know how to make the changes in views noticeable for the manage.py, so it can migrate them. Ive been looking in the documentation and in StackOverflow, but I couldn't find any answer related to this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `makemigrations` only has something to do with the *models*, not the views, so changes in the views are not detected.

Comment: Can you share your `urls.py`?

Comment: where do you add a reference to the `home_view`? Furthermore please [edit] the question, by commenting the indentation is lost.

Answer (score 2):

A view function should always accept the request object as first parameter, and then positional and/or named parameters from the URL patterns, so you need to add a request parameter:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

#             ↓     ↓ request parameter
def home_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello World</h1>')
```

In the video they use `*args` and `**kwargs` to simply catch all possible parameters. It is in my humble opinion better to work with a `request` specify parameters in the function for the parameters in the URL.

In your `urls.py` you should include the `home_view`, for example with:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from appname.views import home_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home_view'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

with *`appname`*, the name of the app.

Comment: okey, for some reason markdowns are not working in my comments, so Ill just say that the only change that I did in urls.py was adding 'from pages import views'. This line of code is the one that throws an error, despite the fact that in the same file they instruct you to import views this way. No matter what arguments I write in the view function, It is still not being detected

Comment: @Germán: but your `urls.py` do only include an `admin/`, you did not specify a pattern for the `home_view`.

Comment: Ive been reading the documentation again, and I know now how to include urls from different apps with include. What I still can't do is import the views as functions or class as instructed in urls.py: 
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Ive tried this and it doesnt work.

Comment: @German: what page did you want to fetch? What is the traceback?

Comment: Ok, turns out it is a problem related to Pylance in VsCode. The error that Pylance throws is "Import pages could not be resolved". I tried changing the settings in the vscode root directory, and if it doesnt work Ill stick with Sublime for Python proyects. Thanks